# Join data table with lookup table to fix bad data

Tags: sql, database

So let's say I have 2 tables:

Data table:

```
CURRENCY       COUNTRY       VAT           MODE
USD            US            FREEVAT       AIR
EUR            ESP           FREEVAT       SEA
GBP            UK            FREEVAT       ROA
```

Lookup:

```
COLUMN_NAME     INPUT_VALUE    OUTPUT_VALUE
COUNTRY         US             United States
COUNTRY         ESP            Spain
COUNTRY         UK             United Kingdom
VAT             FREEVAT        0
```

Is there a way to join these tables in a SELECT statement in order to replace the matches by column_name?
Is there a better structural approach to this problem?

Comment: that's a very bad approach and you should have separate columns or even separate tables to keep the data for different entities ( like in your example country and vat)

Comment: @eshirvana This is a fictional example, what I'm trying to achive here is a process in a chain of processes inside an ELT which will fix the data received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join`, but you need to be explicit about the column names:

```
select d.currency,
       coalesce(lc.output_value, d.country) as country,
       coalesce(lv.output_value, d.vat) as vat,
       d.mode
from data d left join
     lookup lc
     on lc.input_value = d.country and
        lc.column_name = 'COUNTRY' left join
     lookup lv
     on lv.input_value = d.vat and
        lv.column_name = 'VAT'
```

Comment: The 2nd `coalesce` should be `lv` not `lc`. Otherwise very good answer as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works great, but things can get ugly really fast if the number of columns in my data tables gets bigger. Is there any alternative where I can avoid keep adding joins over joins?

Comment: @rstici . . . I can't think of a simple solution for this recoding problem, if you need to do it across multiple unrelated columns.